# How to add an extra class on element after Ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need to add a class on after an ajax load. I first give a few elements a class "ready" which initiate a css transition. When the link li#menu-item-318 a gets clicked it removes the ready class which then reverses the css transition and then loads a new html document.

This is where Im stuck. On the Ajaxload I need to set the ready class again on the same classes on the same elements loaded inside the .test container to once again start a CSS transition for the new page a-swell.

Code:

```
$(function () {
$('.v-line, .h-line, .nav, #ban_image img').addClass('ready');
});


$('li#menu-item-318 a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var linkNode = this;
$('.v-line, .h-line, #ban_image img')
 .removeClass('ready')
 .one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
 function(e) {
$(".js-pageTransition").load("photo.html .test> *");                          
});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you can add a callback function to the `load` that will be executed once the loading is done:

```
$(".js-pageTransition").load("photo.html .test> *", function() {
    //This will run once the new content is loaded.
    $('.v-line, .h-line, .nav, #ban_image img').addClass('ready');
});
```

Comment: Worked great! However, it didn't have the effect I thought it would give. It seems it gave the elements the ready class before the DOm was loaded, so it never started a transition. Without the  ready class my element has a width:0% and with ready class width:100% and a transition between. But after ajax load it only saw the element with the ready class.  Is it possible to set the ready class after the DOM is loaded so the element first gets assigned the CSS for the class withput the ready class?

Comment: Glad it helped. As your code is currently written, the `ready` class is added when the DOM is ready. That is what wrapping it in `$(function() { ... });` does. It seems like your current troubles are not directly related to the question you asked, so unless you can sort them out yourself I would recommend asking a new question.

Comment: Hmm ok. Ill will fiddle around, thanks again this brought me one step closer to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function into jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

```
$(".js-pageTransition").load("photo.html .test> *", function(){ 
    //this will execute after ajax load 
});
```